# Input string without using C++ string

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was asked to take a string (which can be of any size ) from input without using C++ `string`. I thought of dynamically allocating space for a char array and got following implementation from SO itself. But I am not sure whether it is a good implementation. Is there a better implementation for this which doesn't require you to input the number of elements in the name?

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter the size of the dynamic array in bytes : ";
    std::cin >> size;
    char *ptr = new char[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++)
        std::cin >> *(ptr+i);
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you have to avoid using a C++ string? It would be possible to implement this yourself, but it would probably amount to doing the same thing that std::string does.

Comment: @arghbleargh I know that it would be pain to implement it and its just waste of time but I was asked this in an interview.

Comment: A string normally does not have its length prepended to it in an input file. Rather, it is delimited by something (a whitespace, a null character, a newline, or something else). The idea is that you don't know the length until you hit the delimiter. Otherwise reading a string of *any* length is no different from reading a string of some *known fixed* length, and it makes no sense to base a homework on such an easy question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly bending the rules (or I don't understand the question, but...). Anyway, when someone says "dynamic array" with C++,  I naturally think of a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<char> vec;
    copy(istreambuf_iterator<char>(cin),
         istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
         back_inserter(vec));
    vec.push_back(0);
    cout << vec.data() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Think that will do it.

---

**The short version**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<char> vec {istreambuf_iterator<char>(cin),
                      istreambuf_iterator<char>()} ;
    vec.push_back(0);
    cout << vec.data() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even better, initialize the vector instead of using `std::copy`.

Comment: @chris. lol. I'm always forgetting I can do that. My compiler generally yells at me about a MVP when I do because I fail to add the parens like a total nuub.

Comment: Yes, I've done the same thing more than once. Uniform initialization helps it along.

Comment: Stealth down-vote FTL. (my week has really not been good at all).

Comment: @Rapptz its not in a header, and is self-contained, otherwise I would have `std::` sprinkled all over this thing. Thanks for the +1, btw. Glad you (kinda) liked it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char *s;
int buflen = 10;
int len = 0;

int main() {
  s = new char[buflen];
  char c;
  while (cin >> c) {
    s[len++] = c;
    if (len >= buflen) {
      // need to allocate more space
      char *temp = new char[buflen * 2];
      memcpy(temp, s, buflen);
      delete s;
      s = temp;
      buflen *= 2;
    }
  }
  s[len++] = '\0';

  cout << "Your string is: " << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: So many things wrong with this answer I don't know where to start.

Comment: What are some things you don't like about it?

Comment: Manual memory management, `using namespace std;`, `<cstring>`, allocating twice the size.

Comment: This isn't supposed to be production quality code; it's geared towards answering the question as an interview question (see comments). Obviously if you really wanted to do this you would just use std::string. I assumed the point of the question is to demonstrate a basic understanding of dynamic arrays. Of course it could also be to implement std::string "properly", but that seems less likely.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Manual memory management, `using namespace std;` and `<cstring>` aren't *evil* or *wrong*. It's a programmer's choice whether to use them or not.

Comment: @Oleksiy In this particular case, there are better ways to solve the problem. `<cstring>` can always be replaced by C++ equivalents, and you can qualify all of your code explicitly with `std::`. If a programmer uses them needlesly, it's his choice, but it's a wrong choice.